# Dojo and Spring

Tags: jsp, servlets, spring-mvc, dojo

I have created a **JSP** through which I am calling a **Dojo** dialogue (On click of a button).

But the code of the Dialogue ie.,

```
<div>
................... 
</div>
```

is present on the same page.

Therefore I am unable to **insert a controller** (Servlet) in between the JSP  and Dojo Dialogue.

Please suggest a convenient way to insert a controller between Dojo dialogue and JSP.

Thank You
Vishal Saxena

Comment: Your code snippet is a bit... vague ! Can you show us the full code of your jsp including the javascript part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then I suppose you want to use the `href` attribute (then it will load the content in the dialog from an external page -> JSP).

The example code:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" title="My external dialog" href="yourJsp.html">
    ....
</div>
```

Is that what you meant?

**EDIT**: And in your controller you map it like:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/yourJsp.html")
        public String getDialog(ModelMap model) {
                ... // Do your stuff
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dimitri, Actually I want to use values of some elements of current JSP in this particular DOJO Dialogue. Which can be achieved by the controller. In your solution I am unable to see how I can do this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, what do you mean by "some elements"? My solution is only loading the dialog's content from another source (so that means you can use a seperate dialog model/view).

Comment: I have a button on current JSP which "onclick" invokes a function that calls this DOJO Dialogue (whose <div></div> is present on the same JSP). How to get the same DOJO Dialogue by going through a controller first

Comment: Well, my solution does that. As you can see in the example code I have a `href` attribute, you just say what page should be loaded, you map that page on your controller and there you have it, your dialog will be loaded from the model/view provided by the controller.

Comment: @user2293528 I modified my solution with what I meant, I added the code how I would achieve it in the controller (I'm used to annotated controllers).

Comment: Hi Dimitri, @Anyone: How to take value of elements (through request object) to the "YourJsp.html". Because when I'll submit the jsp form here, the dialog box will call "YourJsp.html/ controller" with a fresh request and none of the elements will retain their values. <<PS: Apologies for silly/ easy questions, I am very new to Dojo + JSP + Spring>>

Comment: You can add some query parameters to the HTML page of the href, for example `href="yourJsp.html?param1=test&param2=bla` and in your controller you can get those with `@RequestParam`.
But could you update your question with some kind of a story? So what you expect it to do (and what should be submitted and displayed in the dialog)? I have no clue in what context I should put this.

Comment: Dimitri, I plan to put some Charts on this Dojo-dialog. The input to the charts are: Multiselect Dojo  and 2 Dojo datetextbox elements which I am setting in the JSP where the Dialogue's <div></div> is present. So when the Dialog gets opened-up, it's showing an error because it's unable to find the value of these elements(& NullPointer exception in Eclipse). Also I am modifying these Dojo elements , therefore in "<div></div>" 's href I am calling a controller which in turn returns a jsp page.

Comment: Lastly my Href is something like the following: href="Controller.do". I hope I have given enough details.